# creating dropdown using table view in titanium

Tags: drop-down-menu, titanium, titanium-mobile

i am creating a form containing a dropdown with default value and options to choose. and form should have reset button to clear choosen option from dropdownor tableview.when i click on dropdown it should expand containing options to select and when user selects option it is collapsed.and if reset button is pressed dropdown value is reset to default value.

i searched in google and i got some code below in this code when i executed i am just getting a table view with expanded ,when i select a row it still remains expanded.

```
 var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
title: 'Title goes here',
backgroundColor: '#123456'
});
var checkFlag = true;
var picker = Ti.UI.createPicker({ width:110,left:190,top:150}); 
var data = []; 

data.push(Titanium.UI.createPickerRow({title:'Karnataka'})); 
data.push(Titanium.UI.createPickerRow({title:'tamilnadu'})); 
data.push(Titanium.UI.createPickerRow({title:'kerala'})); 
data.push(Titanium.UI.createPickerRow({title:'goa'})); 
picker.add(data); 
win.add(picker);

var resetbtn = Ti.UI.createButton({
top : '100',
width : '50',
height : '35',
title  : 'Reset'
});
win.add(resetbtn);
resetbtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
Ti.API.info('checkFlag = ' + checkFlag);
if(checkFlag) {
   picker.hide();

    checkFlag = false;
} else {

   picker.show();
checkFlag = true;
}
});
win.open();
```

and is it good to create dropdown using table view or picker and how to set to default value on pressing reset button.please help me i am new to titanium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are getting confused in [TableView](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableView) and dropdown. These two are different elements and have different usage.

I will suggest to use [Titanium.UI.Picker](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Picker) to create dropdown list. Also to make some value of the picker to be selected programmatically you can use [`setSelectedRow()`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Picker-method-setSelectedRow) method of picker.

Following code will help to start things :

```
Ti.UI.backgroundColor = 'white';
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
  exitOnClose: true,
  layout: 'vertical'
});

var picker = Ti.UI.createPicker({
  top:50
});

var data = [];
data[0]=Ti.UI.createPickerRow({title:'Bananas'});
data[1]=Ti.UI.createPickerRow({title:'Strawberries'});
data[2]=Ti.UI.createPickerRow({title:'Mangos'});
data[3]=Ti.UI.createPickerRow({title:'Grapes'});

picker.add(data);
picker.selectionIndicator = true;

win.add(picker);
win.open();

var resetbtn = Ti.UI.createButton({
    bottom: '10',
    width : '50',
    height : '35',
    title  : 'Reset'
});
win.add(resetbtn);
resetbtn.addEventListener('click', resetToDefault);

function resetToDefault() {
    picker.setSelectedRow(0, 0, false); // select Bananas, i.e index 0
}
```

Comment: sir thanks for giuding me.i am doing a form validation in which by pressing submit button form should be validated whether user has selected options  other than default value.how to check this condition

Comment: What I usually do is, I open the picker onclick of a button (by default button has some [title](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Button-property-title)). Then whenever there is some change in picker value, I replace button text with the new value. So while validating I only check if the button has default title or not.

Comment: If still unclear, maybe ask another question. I will try to explain in more detail.

Comment: by using picker.getSelectedRow(0).id==0 in submit button on click i am able to check whether user as selected or not